# Security on Javascript Looping on HTML Form Submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, webserver

I had a random thought while going through several of my web pages. Some of them are using Ajax calls to do POSTs. And of course, the POST is being done through javascript without the client page refreshing. In some cases - the action it POSTs to is an async function.

With that scenario in mind - could the client just simply change the javascript code to loop continuously and furiously keep POSTing, in turn, overloading the server? Although the client could loop even if the function wasn't async, I'm going to assume it's even more dampening with an async function to POST to.

Is this a common scenario that I need to keep in mind of for security issues? Or should I just setup a server-side application/monitoring tool to prevent this sort of spam request? (I guess I could build in a hard-stop in the code, too)

Comment: This sort of denial of service attack is possible in many languages.  The language used would make little or no difference in how it would be handled on the server.  This question has little to do with JavaScript, or even programming

Comment: Yes, this can be something to worry about, and as you mentioned yourself, the best solution is to have a *server-side* rate-limiter, because a client-side rate limiter is not sufficiently trustworthy.